# What would be the Git Workflow - Single Product, Many clients?

Tags: git, github, git-workflow

I work in a product development company. We have a CMS application which was developed on MEAN stack and we use Jenkins CI for automating deployments. We use github for hosting our code.

We receive requests to implement new features from our clients and these features should only we available to the clients who request them since these are meant to custom tailor the application to suit their particular requirements.  We may also roll out new features/fixes on our own which will be available to all the clients.

What workflow should be best suited for the above mentioned scenario, to ensure that the development process and release cycles are smooth.

Comment: Git is not a solution to this problem. It's purpose is not to maintain an ever-growing series of diverging products in a single repository. You should build your modules of functionality in such a way that they are themselves version-controlled products, which you can *plug into* each client site as required. Use Git to manage the bug fixes, use a real plugin system to develop plugin-style functionality.

Answer (score 1):

A Github-centric way to do this would be to create a private repository for every one of your clients that is a fork of your main repository. The client repositories would have two branches: `master` which tracks the main development branch in the original repository and `project` which shows the code that you're developing for them.

Locally, you would have one cloned repository with many remotes, one for each client repository. You would work on a `project1` branch locally for Client 1 and push those changes to the remote associated with that client. You would have a `project2` branch for Client 2 and push to that client's remote. And so on.

When you make changes to your main development branch, you would push this to your main repository and to all of your client repositories `master` branches. These changes could then either be `cherry-pick`ed to the client's project branch or the project branch could be `rebase`d on top of the newly-updated `master` branch.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have one branch for a customer, and a main branch that contains all the core features.

you push for a customer branch for a specific requirement, but when you release a new version of the main product, you rebase all the customers branches.

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question of how to keep the branch for the customer private